# SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field

style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Using `3.7` version of `apache-poi`
I am getting the following issue. Please help on this  .

```
SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Thanks,
Govardhan

Comment: really 3.7 or 3.17?

Comment: poi 3.17 version

Answer (score 14):

According to the javadoc from version 3.17 that field was removed.

Use `FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND` instead.

From source code of apache-poi 3.15 I can see:

```
/**
 * Fill Pattern: Solidly filled
 * @deprecated 3.15 beta 3. Use {@link FillPatternType#SOLID_FOREGROUND} instead.
 */
@Removal(version="3.17")
static final short SOLID_FOREGROUND = 1; //FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND.getCode();
```

Comment: If i use the FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND then i'm getting the following issue again.
FillPatternType cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You need to import it as well

Comment: I already imported these two packages but still it's not helping               import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;                              
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

Comment: If you are able to import it (which means that you are not getting a compilation error in the import statement) you should be able to use it as well in your method. Without your project setup (libraries etc.. ) I'm not able to help you further. Consider pushing your code somewhere and we will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType. It has an attribute FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND or you can pass the value 1.

style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

or

style.setFillPattern(1);